# Converting categorical matrix to frequency matrix using 1000 random sample

Tags: r, matrix

lets saying there is a matrix stored 1000*10 categorical data,

```
> head(edu10)
[[1]]
 [1] trade       somecollege somehigh    collegegrad highgrad   
 [6] collegegrad highgrad    somehigh    collegegrad highgrad   
7 Levels: collegegrad highgrad lessthan8 somecollege ... unknown

[[2]]
 [1] collegegrad somehigh    trade       highgrad    lessthan8  
 [6] somecollege highgrad    collegegrad highgrad    trade      
7 Levels: collegegrad highgrad lessthan8 somecollege ... unknown
```

How do i plot the histogram of the matrix to count how many education? mean of the this?

Comment: This is not an R matrix but more likely an R list.

Comment: Looks like you have a `list` of `vectors`.  Try `barplot(table(unlist(edu10)))`

Comment: Right. A list of vectors. how do i turn this into frequency table and plot the histrogram?

Comment: Thank you @akrun it works!! How do i find out their mean and variance then?

Comment: `mean(table(unlist(edu10)))`

Comment: Great! @akrun how to sort the plot based on specific order?

Comment: @YiHao Do you need to order by the frequency?  If you need a custom order use `factor` and specify the `levels` in that order i.e. `Un <- unlist(edu10); table(factor(Un, levels=c(<your levels>)))`

Comment: @akrun want to sort them from lowest education level to the highest, then plot the chart next.

Comment: In that case `tbl <- table(unlist(edu10)); barplot(tbl[order(tbl)])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
barplot(table(unlist(edu10)))
```